# Example for file read/write with NSFileHandle

Tags: objective-c, file-io, filereader, filewriter

Are there good examples for doing file read/write in chunks with objective c? I am new to objective-c and iPhone API, here is the sample code that I wrote. Are there better ways to do it?

```
-(void) performFileOperation
{
    @try {

        NSFileHandle *inputFileHandle;
        NSFileHandle *outputFileHandle;

        //check whether the output file exist, if not create a new one.
        NSFileManager *morphedFileManager;

        outputFileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

        if ([outputFileManager fileExistsAtPath: self.outputFilePath ] == NO)
        {
            NSLog (@"Output file does not exist, creating a new one");
            [outputFileManager createFileAtPath: self.outputFilePath
                                        contents: nil
                                      attributes: nil];
        }

        NSData *inputDataBuffer;

        inputFileHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath: self.inputFilePath];

        NSAssert( inputFileHandle != nil, @"Failed to open handle for input file" );

        outputFileHandle  = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath: self.outputFilePath];

        NSAssert( outputFileHandle != nil, @"Failed to open handle for output file" );

        @try{
            // seek to the start of the file
            [inputFileHandle seekToFileOffset: 0];
            [outputFileHandle seekToFileOffset: 0];

            while( (inputDataBuffer = [inputFileHandle readDataOfLength: 1024]) != nil )
            {
                [outputFileHandle writeData: [self.fileWrapper process: inputDataBuffer]];
            }
        }
        @catch (NSException *exception) {
            @throw;
        }
        @finally {
            [inputFileHandle closeFile];
            [outputFileHandle closeFile];
        }        
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        @throw;
    }
}
```

I get the following exception while trying to write:

```
Failed to process input buffer ( *** -[NSConcreteFileHandle writeData:]: Bad file descriptor )
```

Comment: Does this work? It seems fine at first glance. Maybe you could increase the buffer size to something like 65kB or whatever.

Comment: looks like i was using fileHandleForReadingAtPath instead of  fileHandleForWritingAtPath.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Needs to change `outputFileHandle` line:

```
 outputFileHandle  = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath: self.outputFilePath];
```